# Clicking element after an animated popup closes

Tags: ruby, testing, automation, cucumber, watir

Our website has multiple javascript popups throughout the site. When you click to open a popup, the screen slightly grays and an animated image shows then once loaded the actual popup. When the popup is closed it fades away along with the slightly gray screen. I am able to open and use wait_until_present to click the close button, but my tests always fails because the next element is not clickable. It will work with sleeps but want to stay away from that. I have tried to use other waiting methods for the next element but can't figure out the best way. Below is a example of what I'm trying to do.

```
require 'watir-webdriver'

browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
browser.goto('www.hayneedle.com')

browser.img(:src, 'http://images.hayneedle.com/shared/images/HN_Free_Shipping_Easy_Returns_Low.png').click

browser.a(:id, 'hn_modal_close').wait_until_present
browser.a(:id, 'hn_modal_close').click

#this is the element that is not clickable because the popup is still closing
browser.a(:href, 'http://www.hayneedle.com/bath/').click
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The alternative to waiting for something to be available is to wait until something is not available. In this case, it seems like you should wait for the popup to disappear.

When I ran your code, I got the exception:

```
Element is not clickable at point (449, 142). Other element would receive the click: <div id="hn_modal_bg"></div> (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError)
```

Therefore, we should probably wait for the `<div id="hn_modal_bg"></div>` to disappear. This can be done by using the `wait_while_present` method.

```
browser.a(:id, 'hn_modal_close').wait_until_present
browser.a(:id, 'hn_modal_close').click

#Wait for the gray background to disappear
browser.div(:id, 'hn_modal_bg').wait_while_present

browser.a(:href, 'http://www.hayneedle.com/bath/').click
```

Comment: Oh man Thanks! I was trying that but was using the wrong div, the one right above hn_modal_bg. Thanks again!

Comment: Had success with this technique. We needed to click a button after a JQuery Dialog went away, initially I tried waiting for the button to be clickable, but I kept receiving exceptions. Finally used this approach and now it works every time.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```
browser.a(:href, 'http://www.hayneedle.com/bath/').when_present.click
```

For more information on waiting see http://watirwebdriver.com/waiting/

Comment: Sadly no, with something like that it says that other element would receive the click and the element it gives is a div class that is in the popup. Even if I leave the popup open and do a puts .present? on the element behind it, it returns true. So any of the waiting methods don't work because watir-webdriver thinks its clickable.